# How to declare a global variable to be accessible in the main program and external function?

Tags: fortran

```
FUNCTION G(K)
    G=K**2+L*K+M
    RETURN
END FUNCTION


PROGRAM MAIN

    I=G(6)
    PRINT*,I
END PROGRAM
```

Here I want to declare the value of `L` and `M` globally so that I can use then in `G()` and the main proram.  How can I do this?

Comment: What is the question? What is your problem with the code?

Comment: Be sure to learn modules, see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/2203/program-units-and-file-layout. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Can somebody else re-tag it? I am sure it is a duplicate.

Comment: This one is not *exact* duplicate, but is closely related too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024559/using-global-variables-in-fortran?noredirect=1&lq=1