# How to pass function name in subroutine/function

Tags: fortran

My problem is to pass the names of a series of functions contained in a module to a subroutine in a do loop.

I post part of my code. The modules are in two separate files compared to the main.

%%% FILE testKer_mod.f90

```
module kernel
  implicit none
  contains

  ! POLYNOMIAL 
  function poly(x, ts, ndim, a, param1, param2)
     integer, intent (in) :: ndim
     real*8, dimension(ndim), intent(in) :: x
     real*8, dimension(ndim), intent(in) :: ts
     real*8, intent(in) :: a, param1, param2
     real*8 :: r
     real*8 :: poly 

     r = (x(1:ndim) - ts(1:ndim))

     poly = r**(.5*a)

   end function poly

   ! GAUSSIAN
   function gauss(x, ts, ndim, a, gamma, param2)
      integer, intent (in) :: ndim 
      real*8, dimension(ndim), intent(in) :: x
      real*8, dimension(ndim), intent(in) :: ts
      real*8, intent(in) :: a, param2, gamma
      real*8 :: r
      real*8 :: gauss

      r = (x(1:ndim) - ts(1:ndim))

     gauss = exp(-(gamma*r)**a)

  end function gauss

end module kernel
```

%%%

%%% FILE testSRBF_mod.f90

```
  module srbf
    implicit none
    contains    

  subroutine weigth(nx, x, nts, ts, ndim, s, kernel, StocPar, param, coe, mat)
    integer :: i,j,k,l,m,n
    integer :: info
    integer :: nx, nts, ndim
    integer, dimension(nts) :: ipiv 
    real*8, dimension(nts) :: w
    real*8, dimension(nts) :: s
    real*8, dimension(2) :: param
    real*8, dimension(nx,ndim) :: x
    real*8, dimension(nts,ndim) :: ts
    real*8, dimension(nx,nts) :: phi, mat
    real*8, dimension(nts) :: coe
    real*8 :: stocPar

    interface
     real*8 function kernel(x1, x2, n3, stov, p1, p2)
       integer, intent (in) :: n3
       real*8, dimension(n3), intent(in) :: x1
       real*8, dimension(n3), intent(in) :: x2
       real*8, intent(in) :: stov, p1, p2
     end function kernel
    end interface

    do i = 1, nx
      do j = 1, nts
          phi(i,j) = kernel(x(i,1:ndim), ts(j,1:ndim), ndim, stocPar, param(1), param(2))
      end do
    end do

    w = s       
    mat = phi   
    call DGESV(nts,1,mat,nts,ipiv,w,nts,info) 
    coe = w
  end subroutine weigth 
end module srbf
```

%%%

%%% MAIN PROGRAM test.f90
    program MKRBF

```
   use kernel
   use srbf

   implicit none

   !real*8 :: SelKer
   integer :: i,j,k
   integer, parameter :: n = 3
   integer, parameter :: nKer = 2
   real*8, dimension(2,2) :: ParBound, auxpar
   real*8, dimension(2) :: Bound
   real*8, dimension(n) :: Var, func
   real*8, dimension(n,nKer) :: coe
   real*8, dimension(n,n) :: mat

   !external SelKer

   interface
     real*8 function SelKer(ind)
       integer, intent (in) :: ind
     end function SelKer
   end interface

   Bound(1) = 0
   Bound(2) = 5

   ParBound(1,1) = 1 
   ParBound(1,2) = 5
   ParBound(2,1) = 1 
   ParBound(2,2) = 5

   auxpar(1,1) = 0 
   auxpar(1,2) = 0
   auxpar(2,1) = 1 
   auxpar(2,2) = 1

   var(:) = (/ 0., 2.5, 5. /)

   do i = 1, n
       func(i) = cos(3*Var(i)) * exp(-.25*Var(i));
   end do

   do i = 1, nKer
       call weigth(n,Var,n,Var,1,func,SelKer(i),2.0D0,auxpar,coe,mat)
   end do
end program MKRBF

function SelKer(indx)
  integer, intent(in) :: indx
  real*8 :: SelKer

  select case (indx)
  case (1)
    SelKer = poly
  case (2)
    SelKer = gauss
  end select
  return
end function SelKer
```

%%%

I tried both with interface and with external but the program gives me the same error:

```
gfortran testKer_mod.f90 testSRBF_mod.f90 test.f90 -llapack -o test
test.f90:46:38:

    call weigth(n,Var,n,Var,1,func,SelKer(i),2.0D0,auxpar,coe,mat)
                                  1
 Error: Expected a procedure for argument 'kernel' at (1)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the interface block in the main program

```
interface
  real*8 function SelKer(ind)
    integer, intent (in) :: ind
  end function SelKer
end interface
```

`SelKer` is a function with `real*8` result.<sup>1</sup>  `SelKer(i)` is such a function result.  Crucially, `SelKer(i)` isn't a function with `real*8` result, but such a `real*8` value.  `weigth` is expecting the argument for `kernel` to be a function (which is a procedure).  This is the error message.

Coming to how the external function `SelKer` is implemented: we see such things as

```
SelKer = poly
```

In the function `poly` isn't the function `poly` in the module kernel but a local (default) real scalar variable (with undefined value).  Note the lack of [`implicit none`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24337413/3157076) in the function.

Instead, you want to be looking to be using *procedure pointers*.  This is a broad topic, so I'll just give an indication of the approach.

1. Move `SelKer` to be a procedure in the module `kernel` (removing the corresponding interface block from the main program).
2. Declare the function result `SelKer` to have type `procedure(poly)`.
3. Use pointer assignment for the result, like `SelKer => gauss`.

There are other, perhaps better ways, to structure such a program.  In particular, many would advise against using procedure pointer function results.

---

<sup>1</sup> `real*8` isn't standard Fortran.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, but I do not know how to use the procedure pointer. Can you give me a step-by-step guideline for my case?

Comment: I see you've asked another question about this, before I had chance to write a more complete outline.  I'll leave this answer as it is: it's usually a better way to learn by looking elsewhere and trying something.

Comment: After your guidelines on how to solve my problem I searched on internet and other posts. However, even for the hurry to solve, I did not find solutions and therefore I opened a new post. Thank you for the answer you gave me anyway because in this way I understood that was the problem and then formulate the questioni better.